# jQuery each ou everything else

Tags: jquery, forms, each

I have a print of list of litle forms with 4 inputs.
This list can contain one or more forms.

I am trying to do update by ajax each form.

How can I do that?
I've tried to do with .each() funcion but no success.

Example:

```
$('form.atusales').each(function(){
     $(this).submit(function({
       var thisid = $('#idsalews').val();    
    })    
})
```

How can I get each $('#idsalews') from each form?

Any help, will be apprecciate.

Comment: you shouldn't have multiple things on the same page with the same id

Answer (score 0):

Elements with an ID attribute must be unique, if you have multiple forms with an element your trying to pull from they can't have all have the same ID, thus I changed the code below to find the element by class `idsalews` you can have an element in all your forms with that same class and it'll work.

```
$('form.atusales').each(function(){
    $(this).submit(function({
       var thisid = $(this).find('.idsalews').val();    
    })    
})
```

Comment: The var `form` is not really needed. You can still use `this`

Comment: Your right, since the submit event is still for the current form `this` will still contain the form element.

Comment: No problem, don't forget to finish the whole cycle to your questions; if this answer solved your question, please mark the question as answered by checking the box next to this answer (**[see this for more info](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)**). This helps build up your own reputation which will only benefit you and the community by letting others know what solved your problem.